# Text Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a program for a class and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. I've worked with Java before, but it's been a while and I'm really rusty. The purpose of this program is to prompt a user to enter a phone number represented by letters (for example CALL HOME would be 225-5466), the program is then to display the phone number based on the letters entered.

We are supposed to store the letters entered by the user into an array and then convert those letters into the actual phone number. Here's what I'm getting stuck on at the moment, I've only worked with arrays consisting of numbers so am not sure how to set this one up. I'm assuming that each index would be one letter, but how would I break the string entered by the user down into individual char characters?

I'm still in the process of thinking through how this program should work and putting it on paper so haven't actually started coding yet, so I apologize for not having any code to share. But this is what I'm thinking would need to happen once the letter representation of the phone numbers were placed in the array:

Declare variables for each letter, like

```
int a = 1 
int b = 1
int c = 1
int d = 2
```

etc. Or is there a more efficient way to do that? Then use if statements for each index like,

```
if [0] == a || b || c 
    [0] = 1
if [0] == d || e || f
    [0] = 2
```

and so on. Like I said, I'm really rusty and am just trying to think my way through this right now before just throwing code at the screen haha. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try using a hash.

Comment: provide an example input - output! What does the user enter, and what do you want to return for that example?

Comment: Maybe just throwing code at your screen is actually the right approach. It's a simple enough program, so get in touch with your inner geek and let the project flow organically, based on instinct. You'll get a lot more out of the exercise by suffering through the problems, rather than asking for help before you actually need it. Save your questions for when you run into a specific problem.

Comment: Split a string into characters with `String.toCharArray()`. What else are you stuck on specifically, I don't want to give a complete answer to a class assignment :-) +1 for MarsAtomic.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That's really the only thing specifically that I've ran into so far @DaveMorrissey, the rest was mainly just seeing if there might be a more efficient way of doing what I needed to do than what I listed since it's been a while since I've worked with Java and I wasn't actually good at it when I was in my first computer science course dealing with it. Doesn't help that my most recent programming experience has been Visual Basic, so I"m trying to write everything in that ha. Thanks again!

Comment: It's tempting to get hung up on finding the most beautiful or efficient solution, but you can look for that once you have one that works! Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`String#toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()):

```
char[] characters = string.toCharArray();
```

You can then get the individual characters from a string.

You *could* use a series of `if` statements to see what characters map to what number. But there are more-elegant approaches. I am not sure if you have used `Map<K, V>`, but you could set up a `Map<String, Integer>` that maps a letter to its integer representation. Then you'd simply have to iterate over the characters in the string and look up their value.

Since this is homework, this is about as much information that I think is appropriate. Using what I have given you, you should be able to come up with an algorithm. Just start writing the code even if you don't know what the end result will look like. This will give you the following advantages:

- Give you a clearer idea of the problem.
- Will familiarize you with the problem-space.
- Will help you visualize and understand your problem and the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much! And this is exactly the kind of help I was looking for, having the program written for me wouldn't help me a whole lot with future programs :-)

Comment: One more thing, since the letters placed in the array are input from the user, would I first need to set up a variable for this string? I know normally when getting input you add a statement like int variable = input.nextInt(); was wondering how that would apply here?

Comment: Yes. You would be reading user input into a `String` variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a 2 dimensional array and methods to check the input against it. For example you can do the following:

Create an array `numbers` of length 10. Each index corresponds to a number you have to call.
Now each entry of the numbers array is an array of chars. So in the end you have something like this :
 `numbers = [['w/e you want for 0'],['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i'], ... etc ]`

When you parse the input string you compare each character with a method like this:

```
private int letterToNumber(char c){
    for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        if(contains(numbers[i], c) return i;
}
```

and your contains() method should be something like that

```
private boolean contains(char[] chars, char c){
    for(char x : chars)
        return(x == c)? true; false;
}
```